# How do I install drivers for graphics and sound?

Tags: software-installation

I recently shifted to Ubuntu 12.04 from windows 7. I completely removed Windows and then installed Ubuntu.

However, I can't find a way to download and install drivers for my video and audio hardware like I used to be able to do in Windows. Could someone please explain to me how software and drivers, in general, are installed on Ubuntu. Is installing through 'Ubuntu Software Center' the only way to install them?

My laptop model is: Dell Inspiron 14 N4010 (i5/4gb/500gb). Kindly help. Thanks in advance.