# Newbie question...My Intel DZ77BH-55K came with a windows express installer disk

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

Which obviously, even to me, doesn't work under Ubuntu 12.04.

Does Ubuntu sort everything out for itself, or do I have to find drivers? somewhere.

Along the same lines I have a Nvidia 450 GForce graphics card, plus there is some built in HD Graphics on the Mobo all I get under settings is driver unknown experience standard.

Under startup aplications there is a mention of Nvidia X Server settings?

Again, am I likely to need supplemental drivers.

At the moment all I know how to do is boot into Ubuntu, search the web, and inspect the file system, I am grass green as far as Linux goes.

Comment: 1)  disable the HD graphics (which is from the CPU not the Motherboard FYI) in your BIOS and 2) make sure to purge all previous driver files when you install the new ones + ALSO blacklist the nouveau and intel drivers

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your reply when I responded to John Ramster. I shall look into your recommendations. Not sure as yet how to "blacklist" the nouveau and intel drivers Thanks

Comment: well last I checked, the repo package for `nvidia-current`, `nvidia-current-updates`, etc. usually does the blacklist for you.  I just threw that in there in case you ended up doing the manual driver install through http://www.nvidia.com (which is always great but not recommended for inexperienced users).  Just make sure to **`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`** before you do your driver install.  Also, here is what I meant by "blacklist":  http://linuxers.org/howto/how-remove-nouveau-drivers-ubuntu

Comment: OK, cheers. I guess I have some reading and a lot of getting used to to do. I am pretty proficient with Windose. Win3 to Win7, but I have only ever peered over the shoulders of Linux users previously. I am not finding it to be quite so intuitive, but I guess there HAS to be a learning curve.

Comment: If you're only now starting to dive into Linux, it's a very good time to do so.  So many things have been innovated and are now included by default in most distributions that make usability and user experience much less painful and much more automated (for instance using `apt-get` to manage anything you want to install or uninstall - and the GUI programs to assist with this like Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic).

Answer (score -1):

I found a post that may interest you, have a look at it maybe you will find answers :
[How do I enable the Nvidia Geforce GTX 570?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145439/how-do-i-enable-the-nvidia-geforce-gtx-570?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. After posting I saw a recommended link about "Jockey" and I am mid process improving the driver choice for my card. I am still wondering if I need to do some other driver search for the Mobo itself.