# do i need separate drivers(graphics,sound,LAN) after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install drivers for graphics and sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145407/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-graphics-and-sound)

Respected Sir,
do i need separate drivers(graphics,sound,LAN) after installing Ubuntu 12.04.
my hardware configuration is :

1. Intel Core 2 Duo E7300  @ 2.66GHz
2. 3.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 800MHz
3. 250GB Seagate (SATA)
4. Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family
5. Realtek High Definition Audio

Comment: possible duplicate -- http://askubuntu.com/q/145407/63478

Answer (score 0):

I had similar setup, but E6600 instead of E7300, and 4 GB RAM, and I did not have any problems with drivers.  I actually did not have to load any drivers.  But if the need for drivers come up in your case, just know that help is a click away.