# How to install a driver in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers

I'm trying to install a wifi driver on a Dell E6400 laptop. I found a forum article that pointed to the right drivers, but can't get them onto the system. I'm new to Ubuntu, with only minimal experience of Linux and UNIX.
The "jockey"/Additional Drivers method given in article [How do I install drivers for graphics and sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145407/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-graphics-and-sound) doesn't seem to have a visible option to install anything, so it seems a bit pointless. I also get an error "Downloading package indexes failed, please check your network status" before Additional Drivers displays. Catch 22!
I also looked at Software Center, after reading another posting. This also has no way to manually install a driver (or anything. . .), it's just a big empty shop window.
I suspect I'm missing something important here!

Comment: To help, we'll need further information on your hardware. Please open a terminal and run the `lspci` command. This will give you a list of hardware installed in you laptop. Either upload all of the output to pastebin and edit your question to include the link, or find the line(s) relating to your wireless network chip and directly include them in your question.

Answer (score 3):

If wifi is not working then , 1st time initially you should connect your pc/laptop with cable/LAN network and try these step:-

Open Additional Drivers option in ubuntu                                                        ( press windows key and find "Additional Drivers" or you can also find this option in "system settings"),

it will automatically find correct drivers for your pc/laptop and choose option to select and install it.

Generally it will find wifi, graphic Proprietary drivers.